# Hide axes when drilling from column chart to pie chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, axes, drilldown

I'm using some different charts renderer in Highcharts drilldown. In some cases, my first level is a column chart and the second (or third...) level is a pie.
Everything is working well except some specified settings for the axes (title, color/width) that appear in the pie chart. The expected behavior is entire axis are hidden in case of pie chart.
As example, in the following : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/w3crqofu/ I would like the axis lines and titles to be hidden in the pie drilled charts.

When using a pie in the first level by setting the type as for the second level :

```
type: 'pie',
```

the axes are correctly hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `drilldown` and `drillup` callbacks to customize your chart options, like:

```
events: {
  drilldown() {
    const chart = this;

    chart.title.hide()
            
            chart.axes.forEach(axis => axis.update({visible: false}, false, false))
            chart.reflow()
  },
  drillup() {
    const chart = this;

    chart.title.show()
            chart.axes.forEach(axis => axis.update({visible: true}, false, false))
            chart.reflow()
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ac9hrfj/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.visible